# How can a country operate its embassy in a landlocked country if all that country's neighbours deny passage?

Tags: international-law, international-relations

As countries evacuate their embassy personnel from Afghanistan by helicopter, I'm wondering what would actually happen if all of Afghanistan's neighbours deny use of their airspace for these flights. There are six countries: Turkmenistan, Uzbekistan, Tajikistan, Pakistan, China, and Iran. Presumably the evacuation flights will have to cross one of these countries, and presumably these countries can deny permission.

If they all deny permission, then there's the further question of "how does one get the personnel to the embassy in the first place?". It sounds impossible for landlocked countries, barring some science-fiction style drop from space beyond the [Karman line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line).

If a landlocked country's neighbours all deny passage, how can a country nonetheless operate an embassy in the landlocked country?

A historical parallel that comes to mind is the [Berlin blockade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Blockade). However, I can't find any details for why the Soviets didn't deny its airspace to the Allies, or if they did, how the Allies were able to fly through that airspace.

Comment: *barring some science-fiction style drop from space beyond the Karman line* Elon's working on it...

Comment: "However, I can't find any details for why the Soviets didn't deny its airspace to the Allies" - the air corridors between Allied-occupied Berlin and Western Germany were the only transit corridors actually formally negotiated with a signed agreement, there were no land-based corridors and as such Allied forces had no fundamental right to cross Soviet-held territory but they *did* have a right to fly across it...

Comment: The question is entirely hypothetical except for the Berlin part, which is mostly historical, so better asked elsewhere (H.SE), and also easy to google an answer for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Berlin_Air_Corridor

Comment: And, yeah, there where periods in the 1940s when the Soviets [harassed the flights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Blockade#April_Crisis_and_the_Little_Air_Lift), including with fighter aircraft, but were not quite prepared/willing to shoot them down. There were some aircraft collisions though.

Comment: @Fizz it wasnt much better when I was living there in the 80s - the RAF base I was on (RAF Gatow) had one of the only fence-versions of the Berlin Wall about 10 metres from the base perimeter fence, and a huge Soviet tank battalion stationed just the other side in East Germany.  Aircraft taking off and landing at RAF Gatow were routinely harassed, and you could regularly see East German guards taking photos of you as you walked around the base.

Comment: @Moo do you know what the signed agreement is called? I'm getting no relevant results for "how were the west Berlin air corridors negotiated". I do grant, though, that further discussing the Berlin blockade would be off topic for this question (and SE).

Comment: @Allure I cant find a name either, but it seems there were a number of agreements and protocols agreed to and signed in 1944 and 1945 concerning the ongoing governance of Berlin by the Four Powers, so its probable that its nameless as they are generally referred to as the "Quadripartite Agreements".  http://filestore.nationalarchives.gov.uk/pdfs/small/cab-129-95-c-58-246-46.pdf

Comment: @Allure its entirely possible it was part of the Protocol of 12 September 1944 and its amendments, but the full text of those are hard to come by.

Comment: @Moo https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/65804/how-were-the-west-berlin-air-corridors-negotiated Moving the Berlin blockade aspect of this question here.

Comment: it was part of the quadripartite agreements see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Air_Safety_Center "Operations began in February 1946 under quadripartite flight rules Paragraph 4. Paragraph 4 of the rules begins: "The Berlin Air Safety Centre has been established in the Allied Control Authority Building with the object of ensuring safety of flights for all aircraft in the Berlin area. BASC regulates all flying in the Berlin control zone and also in the corridors extending from Berlin to the boundaries of adjacent control zones.""

Comment: @Fizz again, its a vague reference to “quadripartite rules” without actually referencing them - seems to be a common theme.

Comment: How on Earth is this question getting close votes for "needs more focus"? There's only one question and that's the one in the title. Seems to me like people are focusing way too much on the Berlin blockade paragraph even though that paragraph contains literally zero question marks. I'm tempted to outright delete it.

Answer (score 4):

A totally surrounded country either has a transit agreement or it has a problem.

- For instance, a German exclave in Switzerland applies [Swiss tax rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCsingen_am_Hochrhein#Taxation) because using German ones would be a impractical.
- The Berlin blockade is no parallel at all, Berlin was governed by the armistice [agreements after WWII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potsdam_Agreement) which spelled out transit rights. The US appeared ready to go to war over a closure of the air corridors, so they stayed open.
- Article 40 of the [Vienna Convention](https://legal.un.org/ilc/texts/instruments/english/conventions/9_1_1961.pdf) on Diplomatic Relations spells out requirements for transit countries, which do not include granting a visa in the first place. If a visa is granted, they have to respect diplomatic privileges.

Comment: The link you give for the Berlin blockade dates to 1972, which is after the Berlin blockade. Wrong link?

Comment: I notice you've amended the link to the Potsdam agreement. According to the link Moo gave in the comments, the actual agreement was made on 30 November 1945, which is after the Potsdam conference. I am going to redirect this aspect of the question to the History SE, though, since it's irrelevant to the question asked in the OP.

Comment: Right, that one reconfirmed the Berlin status. In German one is the Viermächteabkommen, the other is the Viermächtestatus.

Comment: @Allure, there is Yalta with the principles and the London protocol setting boundaries, confirmed by the Potsdam protocol after the cessation of hostilities. There were provisional corridors prior to Potsdam.

Comment: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/65804/how-were-the-west-berlin-air-corridors-negotiated Moving the Berlin blockade aspect of this question here.

Comment: The earlier quadripartite agreements did non have a version in German. The 1945 one establishing the [BASC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Air_Safety_Center) almost certainly falls in this category.

Comment: UNCLOS grants landlocked countries a right of transit.

Comment: @phoog, "The terms and modalities for exercising freedom of transit shall be agreed," see my first sentence.